# Caddy ratelimit for generated resources

Tags: rate-limiting, caddy

I am trying to deploy caddy server with ratelimit (https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/http.ratelimit) for my API which has mutiple resources, e.g.:

http://myapi.com/resourceA 
http://myapi.com/resourceB 
http://myapi.com/resourceC

These resources are created by the users and I don't know their names. What I need is a ratelimit of ~5 requests/minute per resource per IP. 
So if a users sends 5 requests to http://myapi.com/resourceA he should still be able to send another 5 requests to http://myapi.com/resourceB.

Is there any way to do this with caddy? Or does anyone have a good idea how to do this?

Thanks!